# Open mutiple pdf files in separate tabs

Tags: java, liferay-6

Hi I am trying to open multiple pdf files on a click , I am trying in this way.

Considering user will select multiple options to get pdf files by selecting multiple radio buttons.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>sendRedirect Program using Servlet</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form name="pdf" target="_blank" method="get" action="http://localhost:8080/SendRedirectProg/sr">
  <table border="1" width="500">
   <tr>
    <td>Select PDF:</td>
    <td><INPUT type="radio" name="pdf" size="20" value="PDF 1">PDF 1
          <INPUT type="radio" name="pdf" size="20" value="PDF 2">PDF 2
          <INPUT type="radio" name="pdf" size="20" value="PDF 3">PDF 3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><INPUT type="submit" size="20"></td>
   </tr>
  </form>
  </table>
 </body> </html>
```

So consider uer will select all 3 radio buttons and I want to open all these pdf files in different tabs.

I am trying in this way.

```
 import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
public class SendRedirectProg extends HttpServlet
{
  public void method(ActionRequest req, ActionResponse res) throws 
 {
  PrintWriter p=res.getWriter();
  res.setContentType("text/plain");
  String s=req.getParameter("pdf");
  if(s.equals("PDF 1") && s.equals("PDF 2") && s.equals("PDF 3"))
  {
   res.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/SendRedirectProg/DemoPDF1.pdf");
    res.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/SendRedirectProg/DemoPDF2.pdf");
     res.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/SendRedirectProg/DemoMCA 3.pdf");
  }
 }
```

but it only displays last one, I am understanding use of res.sendRedirect, but still how we can achieve this ?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open 3 tabs in one redirect. What you can do is use jQuery or javascript

Redirect to a page where you write the url's to 3 different hidden div's or generate the script directly

onload of the page, use javascript to open them.

```
window.open(url1,'_blank');
window.open(url2,'_blank');
window.open(url3,'_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

`target="_blank"` is your answer ;)

```
<form name="pdf" method="get" target="_blank" action="http://localhost:8080/SendRedirectProg/sr">
```

More information: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

There is also problem in your java code, you should use only one redirect, accordingly to passed value.

```
if(s.equals("PDF 1"))
{
    res.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/SendRedirectProg/DemoPDF1.pdf");
}

if(s.equals("PDF 2"))
{
    res.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/SendRedirectProg/DemoPDF2.pdf");
}

if(s.equals("PDF 3"))
{
    res.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/SendRedirectProg/DemoMCA 3.pdf");
}
```

Comment: Hey @Skriptotajs , I have used it, but it only opens last one (pdf)in a new tab.So I need guidance from backend side

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice error in your java code I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. but as per your implementation also it only opens last pdf i.e PDF3.This is the behavior of sendRedirect.

Comment: It should open exactly one pdf, corresponding to choice of radio input button. You can't choose more than one radio button at time. I would suggest to output "s" value instead of redirecting for debugging purposes.